# Undefined constant Traits in PhpStorm 2016.2.1

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, phpstorm, traits

I am developing with Laravel 5.3 and everything works fine but PhpStorm keeps squawking at the namespace every time I use "Traits", like this:

[image: Print Screen]

Please note that the code works fine, no errors whatsoever so I'm guessing this is a PhpStorm's issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`? It helps IDEs keep track of namespaces and functions. You can also try running `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Yes -- this looks like Parser issues when namespace contains words that are similar to PHP keywords (`Trait`s in your case). See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5015 . Try cutting whole text into clipboard and then pasting it back -- does it help. if not -- try `Code | Analyze` for this file only. If still nothing -- try restarting IDE.

Comment: Hello @aynber and @LazyOne. Yes, I am using `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper` and I've tried `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @LazyOne Cutting the whole text and pasting in back worked! I had tried restarting the IDE but this was the solution. Thank you!

Comment: I fixed it with File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like Parser issue -- happens when namespace contains words that are similar to PHP keywords (`Trait`s in your case).

Things you can try:

- Cutting whole text into clipboard and then pasting it back.
- If still the same -- try `Code | Inspect Code...` and run it on this file only.
- If still nothing -- try restarting IDE.

Other than that -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5015 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on proper fix.